# how to use outer variable in angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-ng-model

I want to change ng-model(degree) value to id(degree_id) in my template as following

```
<md-select flex class="md-select-form" ng-model="education.degree" placeholder="Degree" save-id required-param="{{education.degree_id}}">
 <md-option ng-value="degree" ng-repeat="degree in ['High School', 'Associates Degree', 'Bachelor Degree', 'Masters Degree', 'M.B.A', 'M.D', 'Ph.D', 'other']">{{degree}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

I have used the directive(**save-id**) for this parsing in my controller and i have pulled degree service data and binding the relevant id.The code is following

```
    .directive('saveId', function(Profile){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                requiredParam:'@'
            },        
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log("initial loading");
                // view --> model (change to string)            
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                    var id = -1;
                    var keepGoing = true;                
                    Profile.getDegreeList().then(function(data) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function(ob){
                            if(keepGoing) {
                                if(ob.degree == viewValue){
                                    id = ob.degree_id;
                                    keepGoing = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        //console.log(id); // it gives updated value
                    });
                    console.log(id); // it gives -1       
                    return id;

                });

            }
        };
    })
```

I have updated the model value as mentioned above the problem is ,Only the updated value is available within

> Profile.getDegreeList(){
>   }

Out of this function the value is -1 , what's wrong here?
Please give me the solutions??

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I think it's odd that your directive would return something in it's `link` block.

Comment: Could you provide a Plunk (or other source) of what you're trying to achieve? It's hard to grasp what you're trying to do.

Comment: Consider this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/oDHyEp4YNlgEGpdZrsvp?p=preview What else do you require?

Comment: actually i need to change that value to id bro

Comment: Which value do you mean? Would it be possible to fork that Plunk and add to it to reflect what you need (doesn't have to work)?

Comment: i need to change the ng-model value to selected item'id than keeps it as that value tha's why i have used the directory in my post code bro

Comment: i have used ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){}) for it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the requirements you mention, could you clarify? Right now I'm under the impression that you're making things unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97204/discussion-between-user3391137-and-spikee).

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132574/how-to-execute-the-statement-after-promise-is-executed/34132615#34132615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your call to `Profile.getDegreeList()` is asynchronous.

The `console.log(id)` outside the `getDegreeList` block is executed immediatelly meaning it logs it's defined value of -1.

The `console.log(id)` inside the `getDegreeList` block does work, because at that point the data is loaded.

You should work with [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) ($q).

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but put simply, the following would work:
can easily use the option value attribute to assign the id value to drop-down rather than going through directive.

```
 <select ng-model="education.degree.id" id="degreeList">
    <option 
      value="{{degree.id}}" 
      ng-selected="{{education.degree == degree}}" 
      ng-repeat="degree in degrees">
        {{degree.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

And in your controller (for example)

```
 .controller("myController", [
  "$scope",
  "$http",
  function($scope, $http){
    var self = {};

    $scope.education = {
      degree: {
        id: -1,
        name: ""
      }
    };

    $scope.degrees = 
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'High School'
      }, 
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Associates Degree'
      }, 
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Bachelor Degree'
      }, 
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Masters Degree'
      }, 
      {
        id: 5,
        name: 'M.B.A'
      }, 
      {
        id: 6,
        name: 'M.D'
      }, 
      {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Ph.D'
      }, 
      {
        id: 8,
        name: 'other'
      }];
  }]);
```

Comment: Updated the script to use `$scope.id`. That's the easiest solution, not knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: $scope mean which is isolated scope of directive no?

Comment: Yes, unless it's a parameter provided to the `directive` by a binding in it's `scope` definition.

Comment: i have tried this one bro it updates value but updates wrongly it means updates the value which is previously selected one in drop-down..

Comment: If you use it like this:
`scope: {
 id: '=',
 requiredParam:'@'
}`

`<myDirective id="model.someId"></myDirective>`
? Using the above script, your outside variable `model.someId´ should get updated automatically through two-way binding.

Comment: <myDirective id="model.someId"></myDirective> this is what? it's my <md-select> one?

Comment: I overlooked it earlier, but since you're directive is called `saveId`, it's `<save-id id="model.someId">`.

Comment: i have used as attribute like <md-select save-id ></md-select>, you're saying to attach the id like  <md-select save-id id="model.someId"></md-select> rght?

Comment: As an extension to an attribute, yup! Should work. Sidenote, if `md-select` is yours as well, I'd build it in directly into that, rather than extend your own tag (unless other requirements would force you, ofcourse).

Comment: still it updates wrong value(updates the value which is previously selected one in drop-down)

Comment: Could you provide a Plunk (or something else) for a full sample?

Comment: it seems as you are said problem is because of Profile.getDegreeList() asynchronously execution. do you have any way(context) of execute the code of console.log(id) after the promise has successfully completed?

Comment: My above answer would do it. I don't see why you would need to chain the promise, because it would be strange to return anything in the `.link`. If you need to return something, you should put it in a `service` instead.

Comment: because i need to take the ids for the drop-down menus from service that's why i'm pulling the service

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in that case it should be in the `controller`. Either directly, or by consuming a `service`.

Comment: The actual thing i need to do is as  i mentioned in this post i want to change the ng-model model value as id from string, The ng-model contain the drp-down string value when user selects and save the form drop-down should give the id than name. for it i used that directive to change the model value

Comment: I think you're making things too complex that way, which is why I'm asking for a sample. Easier to suggest specific corrections that way.

Comment: And to detect the selected item id i have pulled that service which contains id and item name values.

Answer (score 0):

Profile.getDegreeList() returns a promise that is evaluated asynchronously. You register some code that is executed when the promise is resolved. Within this code the id is set. However, the line

```
console.log(id);
```

that immediately follows the creation of the promise is executed before the promise is resolved.

If you want to process the id further, or pass it to another function you have to do it within the promise. This means that the line

```
ngModel.$parsers.push(...)
```

has to be pulled into the function that is called when the promise is resolved (i.e. the function passed to `then()`)

Comment: Yah bro i have identified the issue.. however i want to return the id at the end of ngModel.$parsers.push(). how to solve?

Comment: it seems as you are said problem is because of Profile.getDegreeList() asynchronously execution. do you have any way(context) of execute the code of console.log(id) after the promise has  successfully completed?

Comment: The  function passed to the .then() method of your promise is the only context in which you can work with the value. You cannot block until the promise is resolved.