# how to execute the statement after promise is executed?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, angularjs-ng-model

I have used the following directory in my template 
i want to change the model value of drop-down to id for it i have used as bellow

```
  <md-select flex class="md-select-form" ng-model="education.degree" placeholder="Degree" save-id id="education.degree_id" ">
      <md-option ng-value="degree" ng-repeat="degree in ['High School', 'Associates Degree', 'Bachelor Degree', 'Masters Degree', 'M.B.A', 'M.D', 'Ph.D', 'other']">{{degree}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

.directory code

```
    .directive('saveId', function(Profile){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                id: '=',
                requiredParam:'@'
            },        
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log("initial loading");
                // view --> model (change to string)            
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                    var keepGoing = true;                
                    Profile.getDegreeList().then(function(data) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function(ob){
                            if(keepGoing) {
                                if(ob.degree == viewValue){
                                    scope.id = ob.degree_id;
                                    keepGoing = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        console.log("within promise"+scope.id); //it executes second
                    });
                    console.log(scope.id);  //it executes first      
                    return scope.id;

                });
                return scope.id;

            }
        };
    })
```

Once if i try to return the value of ng-model in **finally** block it also not working

```
    .directive('saveId', function(Profile){
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                id: '=',
                requiredParam:'@'
            },        
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                console.log("initial loading");
                // view --> model (change to string)            
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue){
                               // var id = -1;
                    var keepGoing = true;                
                    Profile.getDegreeList().then(function(data) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function(ob){
                            if(keepGoing) {
                                if(ob.degree == viewValue){
                                    scope.id = ob.degree_id;
                                    keepGoing = false;
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }).finally(function(res){
                        console.log(scope.id);        
                        return scope.id;                    
                    });
                });
                return scope.id;
            }
        };
    })
```

i have used Profile.getDegreeList() service to assign the id to relevant drop-down element by using **ngModel.$parsers.push()**. The problem is in case of service usage before promise going to complete it returns the previous assigned id .
i want to prevent it and need to return the promise id. 
how to solve this issue please help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `finally` method which will be executed after executing promise.

```
Profile.getDegreeList()
    .success(function(data)
    {
        angular.forEach(data, function(ob)
        {
            if (keepGoing)
                if (ob.degree == viewValue) {
                    scope.id = ob.degree_id;
                    keepGoing = false;
                }
        });
        console.log("within promise"+scope.id);
    })
    .finally(function(res)
    {
        // your code
    }
);
```

Here you go first make a call and then use parsers.

```
Profile.getDegreeList().then(function(data) {
    angular.forEach(data, function(ob) {
        if (keepGoing) {
            if (ob.degree == viewValue) {
                scope.id = ob.degree_id;
                keepGoing = false;
            }
        }
    });
    ngModel.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
        var keepGoing = true;
       return scope.id ;
    });
});
```

See other [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559341/using-success-error-finally-catch-with-promises-in-angularjs) too for more guidance.

Comment: can we return a value in finally block?

Comment: you can get the value from scope

Comment: can you help me for this issue?

Comment: So you wanted to return id ?? isnt it

Comment: i want to return the id which want to update the ng-model value as i mentioned in my post

Comment: you do not need to return value still you can use that value in controller just use a watch on education.degree_id and on change of education.degree_id do accordingly

Comment: you mean no need directive and ngModel.$parsers.push() ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97195/discussion-between-nglover-and-user3391137).

Comment: Within Profile.getDegreeList() how to access the ng-model value(viewValue) without going to call ngModel.$parsers.push()?